# Is the CSWPFSimpleApp broken in the Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have tried using the CSWPFSimpleApp from the Facebook C# SDK for a couple of days and it has never worked.  I have entered my AppID and it never shows me the appropriate permissions dialog.  It just goes to the generic Facebook homepage login.

Once I log in, it is supposed to pop open a message box with some details about the user, but facebookOAuthResult is always null.

```
    private void DisplayAppropriateMessage(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
    {
        if (facebookOAuthResult == null) //always null here
        {
            // most likely user closed the FacebookLoginDialog, so do nothing
            return;
        }
```

Conversely, I have followed the example listed on this blog and it works perfectly fine:
http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

Is the CSWPFSimpleApp sample broken?  Or am I doing something wrong?

I am using FacebookSDK-5.0.50.0-8305c3f8ea2.src

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change from facebook and a bug in wpf browser control ignores everything in the fragment part of the url which is after #

i have already updated the sample to use a different way by asking from code and then exchanging code for access token. (though i personally would still prefer to use winforms instead of wpf for login only as ExchangeCodeForAccessToken requires distributing the app secret with the app itself.)